# How to lazy load images by class on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, lazy-loading

I have a lot of images on my webpage so I have used lazy loading to help with the performance. I have used one 25kb image as a place holder for all HD images. Normally while scrolling lazy load images display once they come into view, however the images are within a carousel and only the first images changes. I was hoping on click of a button which also displays the carousel I could load the new images by class?

```
<img src="./img/tinyBlur.jpg" data-2x-1="./img/design7.png" class="carosuelImg lazyload-2x loading-lazy hidden">
```

Answer (score 0):

For what I understood, my friend

```
var img = document.querySelector("img");
img.classList.remove("hidden");
img.src = img.getAttribute('data-2x-1');
```

Comment: So in the form  of a button it will look like this? 

$(".blocks").click(
        function(){
        var img = document.querySelector("img");
        img.classList.remove("hidden");
        img.src = img.getAttribute('data-2x-1');
});

Comment: yes, my code will remove "hidden" class from your img tag, which means display carousel, maybe? (if I understand your question right) then it's replace 25kb image to your HD image

Comment: if you are using Jquery, there is a code for much faster:
var img = $('img');
img.removeClass('hidden');
img.attr('src', img.attr('data-2x-1'));
One line style code:
$('img').removeClass('hidden').attr('src', img.attr('data-2x-1'));

Comment: okay man thanks for the help.. I have tried this: $('.carosuelImg').attr('src', $('.carosuelImg').attr('data-2x-1')); but it makes all the images the same?

Comment: I guess you have the class list, then you need to loop it